# How to get repeated number in string?

Tags: regex, tcl

i want to get number of times particular number repeated in a string?
Consider number is 2 , if 22 available in sting means , we should not consider as repeated number.

```
set a "1232163122631261112312"
```

in that 2 is repeated 5 times (we should not take 22 as 2 times repeated of number 2), i want to get this info by using regular expression.

Comment: This is not a job for regex.

Comment: Please, post your attempts

Comment: The asker wants a method to calculate the frequency of a given digit in a string of digits, not counting occurrences where this digit appears next to the same digit. Except for the wording, what is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compact way is probably:

```
string length [regsub -all {[^2]+|2{2,}} $a {}]
```

But there's more to this.

Measuring the frequency of an item in a list is trivial:

```
set freq {}
foreach item $list {dict incr freq $item}
```

The resulting dictionary will have items for keys and their frequencies as values.

If you only wanted to know how many '2's you had in the string, you could use that method (`split $a {}` converts the string a to a list of its constituent characters):

```
set freq {}
foreach item [split $a {}] {dict incr freq $item}
dict get $freq 2
```

But in this case that wouldn't work, since you need to disqualify any occurrences of two or more adjacent '2's. One way to solve that is to remove the offending occurrences before measuring the frequency:

```
set freq {}
set b [regsub -all {2{2,}} $a {}]
foreach item [split $b {}] {dict incr freq $item}
dict get $freq 2
```

Another way is to throw out anything that isn't what you are looking for and then counting what you have left. In this case, what you're *not* looking for is 1) groups of consecutive digits that aren't '2' (`[^2]+`), and 2) groups of more than one consecutive digits that *are* '2' (`2{2,}`), resulting in the regular expression `[^2]+|2{2,}`:

```
set b [regsub -all {[^2]+|2{2,}} $a {}]
string length $b
```

You can also let the `regexp` command split the string into groups of '2's, and then use a rejecting filter operation to take out groups with more than one digit (which conveniently can be treated as integers larger than the integer formed by a single digit):

```
set b [regexp -inline -all {2+} $a]
# -> 2 2 22 2 2 2
set c [lmap item $b {if {$item > 2} continue {set item}}]
# -> 2 2 2 2 2
llength $c
# -> 5
```

Or two nested `regexp`s, the outer getting rid of all words with more than one character:

```
set b [regexp -inline -all {\m.\M} [regexp -inline -all {2+} $a]]
# -> 2 2 2 2 2
llength $b
# -> 5
```

Or you can use some other combination of methods, possibly folded into a single command instead of consecutive commands with holding variables transferring the result of one command to the next:

```
llength [lmap item [regsub -all {[^2]+} $a { }] {if {$item > 2} continue {set item}}]
```

This one replaces all digits that aren't '2' with a space, leaving a string that is also a list of groups of one or more '2's. This list is then passed through a rejecting filter as above.

Or how about this:

```
set b [regsub -all {[^2]+|2{2,}} $a 0]
set c [string map {2 1} $b]
expr [join [split $c {}] +]
# or
::tcl::mathop::+ {*}[split $c {}]
```

which works by replacing offending groups by 0, and then '2's by 1, and then either splitting the string into a list and rejoining it with + characters between each digit, and summing them with `expr`, or by passing each item in the list obtained by splitting `$c` to the `::tcl::mathop::+` command.

Documentation: [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [mathop](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be quicker scanning the string character by character in a loop, but if you insist on using regular expressions:

For the particular example of the number `2`, the regular expression you should use is `2+` (= one or more times the number `2`). Then you can count the number of matches in a loop.

If you want the same for other numbers, then duplicate the process (using `1+`, `3+`, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it through regex you can try

```
(?:^|[^2])(2)(?!2)
```

And count the number of groups.But this might not be scalable.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rJ7hJ6/4